# Errors when trying to extract jar file with java 8 from intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, jdbc, jar, jfoenix

I am trying to extract a jar file with java 8 from IntelliJ using libraries of **fontawesomefx-8.92**, **jfoenix** and **SQLite-JDBC-3.27.2.12**, with this method :

`File > Project Structure > artifacts > Add;` and if I run the jar file from

`out > artifacts > DemoCreditApp_jar > DemoCreditApp.jar` , I encountered these errors :

```
 Exception in Application start method   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
 Method)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
 Source)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
 Source)
         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
         at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown
 Source)
         at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown
 Source)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
 Method)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
 Source)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
 Source)
         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
         at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in
 Application start method
         at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown
 Source)
         at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown
 Source)
         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 com/sun/javafx/css/converters/PaintConverter
         at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField$StyleableProperties.<clinit>(JFXTextField.java:212)
         at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField.<init>(JFXTextField.java:163)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
 Method)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
 Source)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
 Source)
         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
         at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
         at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(Unknown
 Source)
         at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown
 Source)
         at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
         at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
         at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
         at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
         at Views.Main.start(Main.java:27)
         at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown
 Source)
         at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown
 Source)
         at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown
 Source)
         at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
         at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown
 Source)
         at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown
 Source)
         at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
 Method)
         at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown
 Source)
         ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.converters.PaintConverter
         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
 Source)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
 Source)
         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
         ...23 more Exception running application Views.Main
```

I didn't understand what is meant by the error of the path, here is my code source of Main :

```
package Views;

import Controllers.PagePrincipaleController;
import Controllers.SqliteConnection;
import Controllers.Values;
import Models.Patient;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Created by Amine Daikha
 */
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
         Values.sqliteConnection = new SqliteConnection();
        Values.courentPatient = new Patient();
        Values.tableInfo = new TableView<Patient>();
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("PagePrincipaleView.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane = fxmlLoader.load();
        PagePrincipaleController pagePrincipaleController = fxmlLoader.getController();
        pagePrincipaleController.setMain(this);
        //fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(new File("src/Views/PagePrincipaleView.fxml").toURI().toURL());
        //Parent root = null;
        //root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("..\\Views\\PagePrincipaleView.fxml").openStream());
        //Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("PagePrincipaleView.fxml"));
        //Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Views\\ScrollesPaneView.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Transactions Commerciales");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 1050, 570));
        primaryStage.setMaxWidth(1065);
        primaryStage.setMaxHeight(600);
        primaryStage.show();
        Values.pagePrincipaleSage = primaryStage;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(Main.class,args);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox?>
<AnchorPane fx:id="pagePrincipale" prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="1050.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controllers.PagePrincipaleController">
   <children>
      <TabPane prefHeight="570.0" prefWidth="1050.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="CLIENTS">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane layoutX="-1.0" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <HBox layoutX="210.0" prefHeight="430.0" prefWidth="841.0">
                           <children>
                              <TableView fx:id="tableInfo" prefHeight="430.0" prefWidth="841.0">
                                <columns>
                                  <TableColumn fx:id="idCol" prefWidth="150.0" text="Numéro de téléphone" />
                                  <TableColumn fx:id="nomCol" prefWidth="158.0" text="Nom" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="prenomCol" prefWidth="211.0" text="Prénom" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="dateCol" prefWidth="163.0" text="Date de dernier opération" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="prixColA" minWidth="4.0" prefWidth="157.0" text="Endettement actuel (DA)" />
                                </columns>
                              </TableView>
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                        <VBox prefHeight="437.0" prefWidth="210.0">
                           <children>
                              <JFXTextField fx:id="rechercherClient" onAction="#rechercherClientAction" promptText="Rechercher un client">
                                 <VBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="4.0" right="4.0" top="20.0" />
                                 </VBox.margin>
                              </JFXTextField>
                              <Label prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="210.0" text="Ajouter nouveau Client">
                                 <VBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="25.0" top="20.0" />
                                 </VBox.margin>
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="18.0" />
                                 </font>
                                 <padding>
                                    <Insets left="12.0" right="10.0" />
                                 </padding>
                              </Label>
                              <JFXTextField fx:id="numTel" promptText="Numéro de téléphone">
                                 <VBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="7.0" left="4.0" right="4.0" />
                                 </VBox.margin>
                              </JFXTextField>
                              <Label fx:id="errLabelNumTel" textFill="#ee0a0a">
                                 <VBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="15.0" left="13.0" right="4.0" />
                                 </VBox.margin>
                              </Label>
                              <JFXTextField fx:id="nomClient" promptText="Nom">
                                 <VBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="7.0" left="4.0" right="4.0" />
                                 </VBox.margin>
                              </JFXTextField>
                              <Label fx:id="errLabelNom" textFill="#ee0a0a">
                                 <VBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="15.0" left="13.0" right="4.0" />
                                 </VBox.margin>
                              </Label>
                              <JFXTextField fx:id="prenomClient" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="90.0" promptText="Prénom">
                                 <VBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="7.0" left="4.0" right="4.0" />
                                 </VBox.margin>
                              </JFXTextField>
                              <Label fx:id="errLabelPrenom" textFill="#ee0a0a">
                                 <VBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="15.0" left="13.0" right="4.0" />
                                 </VBox.margin>
                              </Label>
                              <JFXTextField fx:id="prixInitialClient" promptText="Valeur de Credit">
                                 <VBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="7.0" left="4.0" right="4.0" />
                                 </VBox.margin>
                              </JFXTextField>
                              <Label fx:id="errLabelPrix" textFill="#ee0a0a">
                                 <VBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="13.0" right="4.0" />
                                 </VBox.margin>
                              </Label>
                           </children>
                        </VBox>
                        <JFXButton fx:id="effacerBtn" layoutX="830.0" layoutY="448.0" onAction="#effacer" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="190.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0fc4e4;" text="Effacer endettements" textFill="WHITE">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
                           </font>
                        </JFXButton>
                        <JFXButton fx:id="modifierBtn" layoutX="530.0" layoutY="448.0" onAction="#modifier" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="190.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0fc4e4;" text="Modifier" textFill="WHITE">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
                           </font>
                        </JFXButton>
                        <Label fx:id="errLabelClick" layoutX="526.0" layoutY="488.0" prefHeight="40.0" textFill="#bc0606">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <JFXButton fx:id="infoDetailleBtn" layoutX="226.0" layoutY="448.0" onAction="#infoDetaille" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="190.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0fc4e4;" text="Transactions" textFill="WHITE">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
                           </font></JFXButton>
                        <JFXButton fx:id="ajouterClientBtn" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="424.0" onAction="#ajouterClient" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="195.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0e9615;" text="Ajouter" textFill="WHITE">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
                           </font>
                        </JFXButton>
                        <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="EDIT" layoutX="685.0" layoutY="475.0" size="18.0" text="" />
                        <FontAwesomeIconView fill="#dd0d0d" glyphName="REMOVE" layoutX="1003.0" layoutY="475.0" size="18.0" text="" />
                        <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="PLUS" layoutX="154.0" layoutY="451.0" size="18.0" text="" wrappingWidth="23.142857551574707" />
                        <FontAwesomeIconView fill="#14860c" glyphName="ARROW_UP" layoutX="387.0" layoutY="470.0" />
                        <FontAwesomeIconView fill="#dd0d0d" glyphName="ARROW_DOWN" layoutX="376.0" layoutY="479.0" />
                        <FontAwesomeIconView fill="#dd0d0d" glyphName="POWER_OFF" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="518.0" onMousePressed="#ett" size="30.0" text="" wrappingWidth="20.714284896850586" />
                        <Label layoutX="906.0" layoutY="514.0" text="Amine DAIKHA © 2019" underline="true" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab text="STATISTIQUES">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <FontAwesomeIconView fill="#dd0d0d" glyphName="POWER_OFF" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="518.0" onKeyPressed="#ett" onMousePressed="#ett" size="30.0" text="" wrappingWidth="32.714284896850586" />
                        <Label layoutX="105.0" layoutY="25.0" text="Totale d'endettements: ">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="18.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="totalEndettments" layoutX="310.0" layoutY="25.0" text="DA">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="18.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Label layoutX="105.0" layoutY="93.0" text="les clients qui n'ont pas payé leurs endettements il y a : ">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="16.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TableView fx:id="tableInfo1" layoutX="105.0" layoutY="130.0" prefHeight="113.0" prefWidth="841.0">
                           <columns>
                              <TableColumn fx:id="idCol1" prefWidth="150.0" text="Numéro de téléphone" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="nomCol1" prefWidth="158.0" text="Nom" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="prenomCol1" prefWidth="211.0" text="Prénom" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="dateCol1" prefWidth="163.0" text="Date de dernier opération" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="prixColA1" minWidth="4.0" prefWidth="157.0" text="Endettement actuel (DA)" />
                           </columns>
                        </TableView>
                        <TableView fx:id="tableInfo2" layoutX="105.0" layoutY="326.0" prefHeight="113.0" prefWidth="841.0">
                           <columns>
                              <TableColumn fx:id="idCol2" prefWidth="150.0" text="Numéro de téléphone" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="nomCol2" prefWidth="158.0" text="Nom" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="prenomCol2" prefWidth="211.0" text="Prénom" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="dateCol2" prefWidth="163.0" text="Date de dernier opération" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="prixColA2" minWidth="4.0" prefWidth="157.0" text="Endettement actuel (DA)" />
                           </columns>
                        </TableView>
                        <Label layoutX="105.0" layoutY="289.0" text="les clients qui leurs endettements passent : ">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="16.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <JFXComboBox fx:id="temps" layoutX="518.0" layoutY="93.0" />
                        <JFXComboBox fx:id="largent" layoutX="421.0" layoutY="289.0" />
                        <Label layoutX="906.0" layoutY="514.0" text="Amine DAIKHA © 2019" underline="true" />
                     </children></AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I have spent the whole day please guide me.